# Why PHP (script) serves more requests than CGI (compiled)?

Tags: php, performance, request, cgi, benchmarking

I developed the following CGI script and run on Apache 2 (http://localhost/test.chtml). I did same script in PHP (http://localhost/verifica.php). Later I performed Apache benchmark using Apache Benchmark tool. The results are showed in images.

## include

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{

    printf("%s%c%c\n",
    "Content-Type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);
    printf("<TITLE>Multiplication results</TITLE>\n");
    printf("<H3>Multiplication results</H3>\n");

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Someone can explain me why PHP serves more requests than CGI script?

Comment: @Dagon I hope you're trolling

Comment: I'd expect a performance improvement from a CGI meant to take a large cpu/memory/io load off of PHP. For example making (a large number of) image thumbnails  or parsing (a large number of) plain-text files looking for something

Comment: @MihaiStancu sure, a properly written native CGI should always beat interpreted PHP.  However you still have to either get over the overhead of starting the CGI before you'll see that performance gain, or use FastCGI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that you're really measuring here is the overhead caused by an almost no-operation program.  The overhead incurred by calling a script or a cgi depends on how your Apache server is configured.  Chances are you're using php as a module, meaning that it actually runs inside the apache process.  For the CGI you're probably using the regular flavor, ie a process is created for every call.

Depending on what you actually want to test/know/evaluate, you should probably rerun this test a number of times, eg with extensive calculations in php vs a C cgi, using fastcgi, and whatnot.  Also, don't forget to check the impact of code caches like APC on the execution of the php code, for certain cases the difference is dramatic.

Comment: Nit: That would make it PHP vs C, not PHP vs CGI ;-)

Comment: @pst agree, but i'm mainly trying to point to some of the facets that he should be aware of, and consider in his test/benchmark.

Comment: How to do CGI script without fork a process on system on each new request?

Comment: @LucasBatistussi using FastCGI

Answer (score 5):

A call to a standalone CGI program results in a `fork` / `exec` - the new program has to be loaded completely.  This is not very efficient.

Iniitially PHP ran this way, but to speed things up `mod_php` was developed, where the PHP interpreter ends up built-into and running inside the process space of the Apache server and all it has to do is some simple parsing.

Comment: [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/) is one method to avoid the fork/exec found with common CGI.

Comment: You could emphasise the fact that the PHP interpreter has spare processes already up and running, I don't know if it actually recycles old processes instead of tearing them down. But AFAIK it keeps a live process pool.

Comment: @MihaiStancu AFAIK with mod_php there's no PHP "process" at all.  Apache does keep spare threads and/or processes hanging around though.

Comment: Does mod_php embed the interpretor into Apache? Wouldn't that be less optimal for static file requests?

Comment: @MihaiStancu yes, it does embed it, but it's only invoked for files registered with that handler (i.e. `.php` files)

Comment: Meaning that when the Apache Daemon `exec`s to satisfy a new `.php` request it `exec`s a binary instance of apache+php while if it's not a `.php` request it `exec`s a binary instance of plain old apache as it were?

Comment: @MihaiStancu no, because in a multi-threaded model there's no need to `exec` anything.  If it's a PHP file, the _already loaded_ interpreter gets passed the file, otherwise the file just gets sent to the client.

Comment: @Alnitak AFAIK Apache2 has two main versions (implemented as modules) one relies more heavily on processes the other on threads (both make use of processes and threads but in different circumstances), it was my understanding that the process version is more heavily used by hosting companies.

Comment: @MihaiStancu I haven't checked recently, but the multi-process version used to be more stable than the multi-threaded version so that may be why.  In any event, what I said above still holds.  It's the `exec` bit that's expensive rather than the `(v)fork`, and with `mod_php` there is no `exec`.